# Persisting some changes before raising an exception in PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I'm trying to write a PL/pgSQL function in which I first validate parameters (mostly check whether the supplied ids exist).

When one of this validations fails, I raise an exception stating the reason so the client code can try again.

The problem I'm facing is that, for safety reasons (I can provide more context if needed, but basically I want to leave the app in a non-functional state until specialized intervention), I'd like to write some values to a table before raising the exception and rolling back the changes. It's only some of these changes that I'd like persisted (not rolled back).

I understand transactions cannot be used inside the function because there's no context, and I found that I could probably do what I want to do using dblink (which I just found out).

The thing is it really feels hackish, so I'd like to ask if this is a reasonable idea or not.

Here's some pseudocode to illustrate:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func(x_id INT) RETURNS INT AS $$
    DECLARE
    BEGIN
        PERFORM * FROM x_table WHERE id = x_id;
        IF NOT FOUND THEN
            -- write persisting values that will prevent further
            -- use, probably using dblink
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid x_id: %', x_id
        END IF;
        -- function logic
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: This is almost certainly not great design.  You're trying to stuff application logic ("if id does not exist, transition app state") into your data layer.  Strongly recommend re-thinking and separating concerns.  That said, you can accomplish what you think you want to do by trapping the error and completing the operation/function on a different path.   See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING

Comment: Hi @BadZen, thanks for your quick response. The thing is all my application logic is running in the database as a set of stored procedures in some private and public schemas. Clients are thin, and only call stored procedures from the public schema. I could not find a good reason to implement my application logic using a different language/stack/process/machine/etc. So far it's working like a charm, using mostly PL/pgSQL and PLPython. Regarding the "trapping error" thing, I don't see how it would help since I want this managed in the function and not in the calling code.

Comment: Even "thin" clients should not be talking directly to a database!  You're encountering classic "why do we need middleware" type problems (synchronizing app state among multiple clients and data).  The fact that you're posting this is a "good reason".   At very least write some SPs that are your API endpoints and return status/success codes and handle errors gracefully - those endpoints are the "calling code" that will catch the exceptions.   Just my $0.02 here, and probably no longer on topic... but there you go.

Comment: The execution of your function (and anything below it) is part of your transaction. If the transaction fails (is *rolled back*) nothing has happend to the DB state. The only ways to "escape" from this is raising notices, asynchronous mesaging, and keeping a second connection open (by the application logic) . And flatfile logging, of course.